# Почему OMSA и iDRAC выдают разные сведения по поводу состояния батареи?

Tags: сервер, centos

Есть 4 сервера DELL PowerEdge R710. ОС - CentOS 7.
В наличии на каждом сервере iDRAC и openmanage server administrator 7.4.1

На двух серверах происходит следующее:
по данным iDRAC с батареей стораджа все ok.
В OMSA веб интерфейсе вижу, что `Battery on Controller PERC 6/i Integrated: State Failed`

omreport показывает следующее:

```
omreport storage battery
List of Batteries in the System

Controller PERC 6/i Integrated (Slot Embedded)
ID                  : 0
Status              : Ok
Name                : Battery 0
State               : Ready
Recharge Count      : Not Applicable
Max Recharge Count  : Not Applicable
Learn State         : Idle
Next Learn Time     : 81 days 4 hours
Maximum Learn Delay : 7 days 0 hours
Learn Mode          : Auto
```

На еще двух серверах вижу вот что:
данные iDRAC говорят, что storage battery OK. Данные веб интерфейса OMSA говорят, что `Battery on Controller PERC 6/i Integrated: State Failed`. 
omreport сообщает, что

```
omreport storage battery
List of Batteries in the System

Controller PERC 6/i Integrated (Slot Embedded)
ID                  : 0
Status              : Critical
Name                : Battery 0
State               : Failed
Recharge Count      : Not Applicable
Max Recharge Count  : Not Applicable
Learn State         : Idle
Next Learn Time     : 58 days 2 hours
Maximum Learn Delay : 7 days 0 hours
Learn Mode          : Auto
```

Кому верить? Как разобраться, в порядке ли батарея?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо через OMSA выгрузить storage controller log, там будут подробные данные о состоянии батареи, из которых можно узнать что с ней творится.
Подобная разница в показаниях утилит может быть вызвана тем, что цикл проверки батареи еще не был выполнен, либо был выполнен давно.